# Merging lines (create one line from multiple lines) using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, line, merge

I have polyline shapefiles with hundreds of line segments - streets, paths, highways. The rules are that a line can be divided only on intersections or when the attributes change. But all of the lines were created by hand by my colleague and there are a lot of mistakes. My main problem is that there are a lot of lines divided unnecessarily. I once found a simple line divided into 14 segments without any reason.

Is there any way how I could merge or at least find all these segments?

Keep in mind that I work with large area and several different layers. (Now I’m just randomly clicking on the lines to see if they’re divided or not which is not a very efficient method)

Comment: Have you looked at the Unsplit Lines or dissolve tools in ArcGIS?  I think one of the ET Geowizards free tools is the export nodes and after doing that you can look at the pseudo nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Topology](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/topologies/topology-in-arcgis.htm) to find and resolve these issues to your satisfaction? It can handle features in multiple layers, it just takes more complex rules.